# RTK query failing in app.jsx of laravel reactjs project

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a laravel (v10.x) project with a reactjs (v18.2.0) front-end. I've successfully implemented Redux (v8.1.2), Redux-Toolkit (v1.9.5) (RTK) and RTK Query to pull a list of 'transactions' from the back end. However, I have a number of lists that will be used throughout the application that I'd like to pull at the root level. That's when things go bad.

I get an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Je.current is null`. I wonder if RTK isn't ready at this point, though the store should be because the React Redux tutorial uses a dispatch at this level before it gets to RTK Query. Unfortunately, the tutorial I've been following (https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced) switches away from using RTK at the root level, while saying it should be the same format.

My app.jsx in the working version is:

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';
import '../css/my.css';

import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/react';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import store from '@/Store/Store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.jsx`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.jsx')),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {

        const root = createRoot(el);

        root.render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App {...props} />
            </Provider>
        );
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

My apiSlice.jsx is:

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'http://localhost:8000'}),
    endpoints: builder => ({
        getTransactions: builder.query({
            query: () => 'api/transactions'
        }),
    })
})

export const { useGetTransactionsQuery } = apiSlice;
```

My Store.jsx is:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// import transactionsSlice from './TransactionsSlice'
import transactionsReducer from '@/Store/TransactionsSlice';
import { apiSlice } from '@/Store/apiSlice';
// import { getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware)
})
```

And my FindTransactions component is:

```
import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout';
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/react';
import React from 'react';
import TransactionDetail from './Partials/TransactionDetail';
import { useGetTransactionsQuery } from '@/Store/apiSlice';

export default function FindTransactions({ auth }) {
    const {
        data: transactions,
        isLoading,
        isSuccess,
        isError,
        error
    } = useGetTransactionsQuery();

    let transactionList

    return (
        <AuthenticatedLayout
            user={auth.user}
            header={<h2>Find Transactions</h2>}
        >
            <Head title="Find" />

            <div className="content">
                {transactionList}
            </div>
        </AuthenticatedLayout>
    );
}
```

This all works well. I can see the data in the Redux DevTools and with a bit of extra code (removed for brevity), I can render exactly what I want.

I thought I should be able to move the `useGetTransactionsQuery` code to app.jsx as:

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';
import '../css/my.css';

import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/react';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import store from '@/Store/Store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { useGetTransactionsQuery } from '@/Store/apiSlice';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Venn';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.jsx`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.jsx')),
    setup({ el, App, props }) {

        const {
            data: transactions,
            isLoading,
            isSuccess,
            isError,
            error
        } = useGetTransactionsQuery();

        const root = createRoot(el);

        root.render(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <App {...props} />
            </Provider>
        );
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

Obviously, I also removed it from `FindTransactions`. This gives me the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Je.current is null`. Given that none of my code uses '.current', I assume this refers to something in RTK not being ready, but I have no idea what or how to fix it.

Comment: React hooks can only be called in React functions and custom React hooks. Redux hooks can't possibly access the provided store value from higher in the ReactTree than the Redux `Provider` component as well, and from what I see here `Provider` is the root component of the app, there's nothing above it in the ReactTree (*in other words, you are trying to use the hook outside React*).  What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I was trying to fetch the data once at the highest level so that it would be available throughout the app. This is done in the Redux-Toolkit documentation (https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#loading-users), so I assumed it was normal practice. As you say, there's nothing above Provider so how can I be doing anything outside it? Or are you suggesting that Provider shouldn't be outside App? That's the pattern recommended by the creators (same link).

Comment: In any case, I've learnt that I can dispatch a query for a single item (transaction) on any page and Redux will fetch the whole list once, so that achieves what I want without adding this query to the root.

Comment: This ***isn't*** the pattern they are using though. They directly dispatch an action on the `store` object, they aren't calling a React hook. A Redux store exists on its own, outside React. Yes, that's the general idea behind the RTK queries, that they can be initiated from anywhere in the ReactTree and the results cached to accessible from anywhere else in the ReactTree (*or where the `store` is accessible*). You could call `useGetTransactionsQuery` from `App` if that's the very top of your app code.

Comment: Thanks for responding and for your patience. I'm afraid my understanding of react isn't up to differentiating between dispatch and a react hook. I've got some more reading to do. Your last statement confuses me though. I was trying to call `useGetTransactionsQuery` from App, as far as I can tell.

Comment: No worries at all. In your last code example you are calling `useGetTransactionsQuery` from the `setup` function (*obviously not a React function or custom hook*), `App` is the `<App {...props} />` that the `setup` is passing to the `root.render` function.

Comment: React hook functions ***are*** functions, same as `dispatch`, but the basic *distinction* between them is that React has defined and established some rules specific to Hooks for when and how they can be used (*Think React component lifecycle*). See the [Using a Custom Hook](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook) section, specifically the "Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”?" subsection.